# Could two different sums yield two different areas?

Tags: measure-theory

I was talking with a professor and from what I understood: If you take a polygon and split it into various pieces:

$$P=p_1+p_2+\dots + p_n$$

One needs to prove that the order of the sum does not alter the result. And mencioned that this is proved via measure theory. But it seems that for some kind of context, he could do it without measure theory. I got curious: If you decompose the area of a polygon in various other polygons, what could possibly go wrong to make the order of the sums yield different results?

Comment: could be this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_third_problem

Comment: There are many interesting things to say here depending on what you mean by piece, but I do not think you are asking the question you mean to ask.  What do you mean "One needs to prove that the order of the sum does not alter the result. "?  Probably you have in mind a partition of $P$ and reconstitution using translations and rotations.  If not, clarify.

Comment: I don't think you've understood your professor's intent correctly (that could be a problem with your understanding or his communicating). That the result of a summing a finite set of numbers is the same for any order, is an algebraic result, not something from measure theory. It does not matter whether you get the numbers as areas or by some other means.

Comment: I think he might have been thinking about the Banach Tarski paradox, which happens when you allow each "piece" to be more like a disconnected set of points.